A very useful object
What is leather and sounds like a sneeze?

This is not my puzzle. I saw it from a friend, but I don't know the original source.

Guys feel free to close if you think it doesn't belong. I just thought it is a nice joke and also a decent puzzle.

I don’t think there is anything wrong about it per se. It just doesn’t sit well for PSE users because, it 1) seems low effort 2) It is a pretty cliché riddle (I think I personally have heard this somewhere). Also FYI, Reddit has a better audience for these kinds of puzzles from what I observed, in fact they love simple puzzles with a tricky logic there from what I have seen.

Thanks for your honesty.

I'm guessing it's

 A shoe (sounds like achoo)


Yep you got it!
